# What are the mathematics behind a disc being elevated by air flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lift

I realize the question title is a little vague...

I was at the Smithsonian air and space museum recently and they had a set-up showing a disc with an air pipe. The pipe is flowing air fairly consistently and facing downward. When you place the disc up to the pipe, my first thought was that it would blow away due to greater pressure on the top of the disc than the bottom. This happened until the disc was close to the pipe and then it was pulled toward the pipe and stuck to it with a small gap.

[image: pipe flow with forces]

So what I was wondering was how this works, mainly if I wanted to calculate the pressure above and below the disc to determine the equilibrium 'float distance', how would I go about doing that based on the air flow, pipe radius, and disc radius, and disc weight? Are there other variables I'm not taking into account?

Thank you.

Comment: I get the feeling this _may_ have to do with Bernoulli's principle and mass conservation, so when you decrease the effective diameter, you increase velocity and decrease pressure of that flow.  My issue is that the standard Bernoulli principle applies to incompressible fluids.  If the fluid were fairly compressible (like air is), the situation and relationships are more complicated, therefore I am not comfortable saying this is really the reason.  Something to look into though.

Comment: Just google "radial flow between two parallel disks". Here's a link: http://www.syvum.com/cgi/online/serve.cgi/eng/fluid/fluid306.html